# How to select multiple rows in QTableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside, pyqt5

I have a table where I've enabled ExtendedSelection:

```
table.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
```

When I close the UI I use QSettings to remember any selected rows. When I re-open my UI I want it to automatically re-select the rows automatically.

I have this, but this ends up only selecting the last selected row:

```
QSETTINGS = [1, 2, 3]  # Indicates row 1, 2 and 3 should be selected

for row in xrange(table.rowCount()):
    table_item = table.item(row, 1)
    row_data = table_item.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
    row_id = row_data
    if row_id in QSETTINGS:
        table.selectRow(row)  # This ends up only making one row selected
```

What should I use instead of `table.selectRow(row)` in order to make sure to select more than just one row?

---

**Edit**

In my original question, I said I was using `QtGui.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection`. However, I'm not. I'm using `QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection`, which is also why my row selection code obviously doesn't work. By temporarily switching to `MultiSelection`, selecting the rows and then switch back to `ExtendedSelection`, the code in my question works great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By temporarily setting `MultiSelection` selection mode, each row is selected.

```
QSETTINGS = [1, 2, 3]  # Indicates row 1, 2 and 3 should be selected

# Temporarily set MultiSelection
table.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)

for row in xrange(table.rowCount()):
    table_item = table.item(row, 1)
    row_data = table_item.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
    row_id = row_data
    if row_id in QSETTINGS:
        table.selectRow(row)  # This ends up only making one row selected

# Revert MultiSelection to ExtendedSelection
table.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
```

Comment: As a side note, if you select all rows it seems to be an easy way to do an invert selection. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setSelected` on each `QTableWidgetItem`

```
for row in xrange(table.rowCount()):
    table_item = table.item(row, 1)
    row_data = table_item.data(QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
    row_id = row_data
    if row_id in QSETTINGS:
        for col in table.columnCount():
            item = table.item(row, col)
            if item:
                item.setSelected(True)
```

Answer (score 1):

PyQt is kind of wrapper on top of usual Qt library. The answer for the question is possible to achieve with the following steps.

**Step-1:** Open documentation for [QTableWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html)

**Step-2:** After scrolling documentation understand that table is organized as rectangles of items

**Step-3:** Understand that it is possible to obtain a number of rows and columns via [rowCount](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#rowCount) and [columnCount](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#columnCount-prop)

**Step-4:** Understand that to obtain the item from a specific row and column is possible with [QTableWidget::item](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html#item)

**Step-4:** Open documentation for [QTableWidgetItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html)

**Step-5:** Find that there is a method [QTableWidgetItem::setSelected](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidgetitem.html#setSelected)

Finally, you can create code like:

```
for r in range(tblMy.rowCount()):
    for c in range(tblMy.columnCount()):
        item = tblMy.item(r, c)
        isSelected = ...
        item.setSelected(isSelected)
```

p.s. So even PyQt is documented as poor or not ideal, usual Qt has rich documentation.

Answer (score 0):

in this example `table.selectRow(i)` is working on multiselection:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyTableWidget(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QTableWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setRowCount(5)
        self.setColumnCount(3)
        self.items = [['a1','b1', 'c1'], ['a2','b2','c2'], ['a3','b3','c3'], ['a4','b4','c4'], ['a5','b5','c5']]
        self.hh = ['a', 'b','c']
        self.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.MultiSelection)
        selected = [1,2,4]
        self.setSel(selected)

        for r in range(0,len(self.items)):
            for c in range(0,len(self.items[0])):
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                item.setText(self.items[r][c])
                item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable)
                self.setItem(r,c,item)

    def setSel(self, selection):
        for i in selection:
            self.selectRow(i)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
widget = MyTableWidget()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

i get the behaviour you described, if i call `setSelectionMode` after setting selection

Comment: Sorry, I was using `ExtendedSelection`, not `MultiSelection`. I now see why only one row is being selected with my code. It's because I'm not using MultiSelection, basically. So temporarily setting that should fix my issue.